# Is there a way to get a larger desktop than the screen?

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, resolution, virtual-desktop

Is there any freeware out there that will allow me to run the desktop that is larger than the resolution of the screen? 
My situation:
Win XP, Dell Mini 10, iirc- Intel GMA950 
I need to use a netbook for one specific web site (with firefox) that doesn't render properly if the screen isn't at least 1024x768.  It is a netbook, so the res is 1024x600. Is there anything out there that will allow me to use a 1024x768 desktop on this smaller screen WITHOUT shrinking the desktop to fit. I want to pan around.
Thanks! 
Cajuntechie

Comment: I know some users reported that they were able to bump up the resolution on their laptops beyond what the screen could (I've seen this done on a netbook). Try increasing the resolution; maybe it fill simply allow you to pan around.

Comment: I believe this depends on what graphics card (and/or driver) - I've noticed this feature exclusively with many ATI and nVidia cards, but that's just my own personal experience.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a nVidia card, the graphics control panel allows this via the `Manage Custom Resolutions` option.

However being stuck with Intel, you need a tool to increase the virtual desktop resolution. The only tool I know of that supports this is [GiMeSpace Desktop Extender Edition](http://sites.google.com/site/gimespace/home/desktop-extender-edition) though reviews on it are extremely mixed, so be fore-warned. :)