# Need a larger desktop on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get a larger desktop than the screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/131288/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-larger-desktop-than-the-screen)

Help!

I desperately need to be able to size my web browser window WIDER than the screen width. But Microsoft XP says "no".

Without Administrator credentials, how can I tell Microsoft Windows XP to make my desktop virtually bigger than the physical screen size?

Comment: Would love a way of kicking Microsoft in the teeth.

Answer (score 1):

One way, would depend on your video card.

many video cards can change to a resolution that is beyond the monitor size itself, and (more importantally) can change to a resolution that is beyond thier own video display buffer size.

When you put the video cards on these extreeme high resolutions, the workspace is then having to scroll around , instead of fitting the display size.

the windows (any of them) maxed or stretched would then be able to have parts of them off screen, and allow for size changes that are beyond the actual max resolutions of the viewed display space.

It would help if we know for what purpose this is needed, before covering other tricks.

like moving the window way off the side of the monitor till little of the edge shows in the display area, THEN grab the edge, size it across the whole monitor, and presto , you should have it 2x wide with half of it hanging out the side. doesnt work maxamised.
When you then have no access to the Bars that allow "Move" you revert to the Hotkey for move, or initiate move off the taskbar. so you can still accomplish a "move".

if i remember right there is a utility that allows maxamised windows to be moved, i do not remember its name though :-(

if the limitations are the browsers (programs) max size ability, then only the video card trick will work, to use normal windows sizing tricks it would help then to have a different browser (program) that will allow for that.

If joe is correct , and the situation is a web page that does not display properly, it is possible that Text Size, and Zoom items could be applied to fit the whole web page into the available spaces.
You can find zoom and text size items in many browsers including newer versions of IE, even if they are not Right in your face now, customising or finding the items they are there.

for IE browsers that do zoom, In advanced properties for Internet options, you can set to have zoom and text sizes Stay that way till you change them. (soes you can continue to explore without it changing back)
Might require a newer versions of IE, a Maxthon browser would do it, and probably many other 3rd party browsers.  sometimes it takes time to find those options hopefully i have made that easier.